# Populate Java Object using Map

Tags: java, reflection, bigdecimal, objectmapper, apache-commons-beanutils

I have a `Map<String, Object>` . Using this, I have to populate one java object. For example,

```
public void setBaseAttributes(BaseObject baseObj) {
  Map<String, Object> map = // some method call;
  org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.populate(baseObj, map);
 }
```

I was using BeanUtils but got stuck since BeanUtils does not handle BigDecimal. My baseObj has BigDecimal and i can not get rid of it.

Question to experts are:

- Is there a better alternative i can use here?
- Using BeanUtils, can we do something to handle BigDecimal also?

Comment: What error are you getting, and what version of BeanUtils are you using? It seems to work with 1.9.3.

Comment: Hi @heisbrandon, I am using 1.9.3 and this is the relevant trace : https://justpaste.it/24lva

Comment: Ok. The issue was not with BigDecimal. I had empty value for big decimal in map and that caused the BeanUtils to fail. I was looking for more reliable which can just form with whatever values are present in map. If there is no corresponding value in map, it should just put null for that field in object. My object contains enum, BigDecimal, Double, String.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment it seems you are having trouble when working with a null or missing BigDecimal value. You can register a different converter for BigDecical with a supplied default value with the following:

```
    Object defaultValue = null;
    BigDecimalConverter converter = new BigDecimalConverter(defaultValue);
    ConvertUtils.register(converter, BigDecimal.class);
```

See the documentation for [ConvertUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/ConvertUtils.html) and [BigDecimalConverter](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/converters/BigDecimalConverter.html) for details. There is also more specific information in the [ConvertUtilsBean](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/ConvertUtilsBean.html) documentation.